# Cannot find module, but module exists and is not required by this bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have an Express server with a React client-side app, I set up my webpack config to output two bundles, one for my server and one for my react app.

I cannot compile my server bundle unless I comment out the shebang at the start of bin/www. If I do comment it out and compile everything I can't start the server because I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'querystring'.
    at /Users/jahansj/Documents/personal-projects/roomshake/app_dist/js/app_bundle.js:51283:42
```

Query string is installed, saved as a dependency and I can see it in my node_modules folder.

I have tried not excluding node_modules from my webpack config as well as using a shebang loader in babel to see if commenting out the shebang was causing the problem somehow.

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = [{

    name: 'dev',
    entry: './dev/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist/js',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: (/node_modules/ || /app/),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style?sourceMap',
                    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

},
{

    name: 'app',
    target: 'node',
    entry: './app_dev/bin/www',
    output: {
        path: 'app_dist/',
        filename: 'app_bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: (/node_modules/ || /dev/),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    }

}];
```